# iphlpapi / ifdef.h

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to use `iphlpapi` (`GetAdapterInfo`) and am having trouble compiling the code.  I have `iphlpapi.h` from SDK 7 and have added the appropriate path to the include files in visual studio.

I get the following error...

> c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0\include\ifdef.h(154) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'NET_IFTYPE'

The lines in ifdef where this occurs are shown below.

```
typedef NET_LUID IF_LUID, *PIF_LUID;
typedef ULONG NET_IFINDEX, *PNET_IFINDEX;       // Interface Index (ifIndex)
typedef UINT16 NET_IFTYPE, *PNET_IFTYPE;        // Interface Type (IANA ifType)
```

Comment: Are you #including <windows.h> before <iphlpapi.h>?

Comment: I thought that too, Nathan, but the page I found has nothing about `windows.h`, only `winsock2.h`

Comment: The error is about UINT16 not being defined. It's set in BaseTsd.h, which is included (indirectly) from Windows.h, which is included by Winsock2.h.

Comment: @GMan, Nathan Howell: windows.h was already included, I added an include winsock2.h but that didn't help.  I threw in a include BaseTsd.h just for fun to no avail also.  I also added a UINT16 zork; just to see if UINT16 got defined and it was NOT.

Comment: Might be worth grabbing the latest Windows SDK to see if it goes away, sounds like something is broken in your environment. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en

Answer (score 5):

I finally figured out how to get this to work so I'm putting this here for others who might stumble upon it.

First, I'm using visual c++ version 6.0 with the 2003 sdk.  I added the sdk as the first choice using TOOLS->OPTIONS->DIRECTORIES.  Adding the include winsock2.h caused about 60 redefinition errors.  I found several sources telling me that the winsock2 include had to precede the windows.h include.  My windows.h include was generated for me by VC++ in the precompiled header stdafx.h so I moved the winsock2.h include there.  I now can compile and run my program!

Comment: VC6 is old and busted. It's not even supported by Microsoft anymore. Don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365872%28VS.85%29.aspx), it looks as though you might need to make sure `winsock2.h` is included first. I'm guessing that it defines some of those types.

Also, the MSDN page for `NET_LUID` says it requires Vista at a minimum. Make sure that's true.